# SQLITE select random row based on 4 conditions

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

Let me preface this with I just started trying to learn SQLite a few days ago. I'm hoping this is easy.

I'm trying to select a random row in a table of names based on some factors.  Basically I have a max year and a min year and a max rank and a min rank (the lower the number the higher the rank in this case).  So What I have is the following:

I have a table named GirlNameRankingsByYear which has the following columns: name, year, rank, occurrences, and parent ID.  the last two of these aren't really important right now.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM GirlNameRankingsByYear ORDER BY RANDOM() WHERE Year<=+'" + Settings.Default.MaxYear + "' AND Year>=+'" + Settings.Default.MinYear + "'" +
                     "AND Rank>=+'" + Settings.Default.MaxRank +"' AND Rank<=+'" + Settings.Default.MinRank+"'";
```

But I this does not work.  If I take out random I can generate a name with my conditions, but of course it generates the same name every time.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to set `ORDER BY RANDOM()` at the end of the query

Comment: yes that works, but what I'm doing then is actually then just finding one year in that range that meets the conditions.  Is it possible to find a random row where all of the same name within that range meets the conditions?

Comment: If you did not specify all conditions, edit your question. If you want to ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button.